# How to retrieve only records that are not deleted from database in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have recommends table that has `product_id`, `user_id` and `deleted_at` columns and I want to display the most viewed products in the view and it works fine but the problems is when user deletes the product I get an error `trying to get property of non object` and the column `deleted_at` in recommends table still showing null even if the product is deleted. How can I make the product disappear in recommends table after the product has been deleted and the view should display only the products which are not deleted?

Controller

```
  $recommends = Recommends::with('product')
    ->select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total'))
    ->whereNotNull('product_id')
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->orderby('total', 'DESC')
    ->take(12)
    ->get();
```

Recommends.php

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recommends extends Model
{
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id')
}
}
```

Product.php

```
 public function recommends()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recommends','product_id');
 }
```

Comment: Are you using `softdelete`? If yes show your Product.php model code and delete code?

Comment: No I just have the deleted_at column @DilipHirapara

Comment: Are you using relationship in table ?

Comment: Yeah I use relationship in table @YasinPatel

Comment: So we you delete product, it is not removed from recommand table?

Comment: I tried to use soft delete in models and adding with Trashed but the product was still there even if it is deleted @SalmanZafar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `wherehas()` it will check that product exist or not:

```
$recommends = Recommends::with('product')
    ->select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total'))
    ->whereNotNull('product_id')
    ->wherehas('product')
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->orderby('total', 'DESC')
    ->take(12)
    ->get();
```

And also on delete product remove all recommendations for that product.

Change in Product model,

```
protected static function boot() {
   parent::boot();

   static::deleting(function($product) {
     $product->recommends()->delete();
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the method in products model works @Yasin Patel